# mongodb compound index and single index performance

Tags: mongodb, compound-index

Consider the following scenario:

100% of the time my query will include **a** in the query, and sometimes also **b**.

90% the query will be:

```
{a:"somevalue"}
```

and 10% it will be

```
{a:"somevalue",b:"somevalue"}
```

What would be the downside to satisfy this with a compound index only (if any)?, like so:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1
    },
    "name" : "a_1_b_1",
    "ns" : "foo.bar"
```

}

Or would i benefit from adding a second index satisfying only queries on **a**

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1
    },
    "name" : "a_1_b_1",
    "ns" : "foo.bar"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
            "a" : 1
    },
    "name" : "a_1",
    "ns" : "foo.bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix) has this to say;

> If you have a collection that has a compound index on { a: 1, b: 1 }, as well as an index that consists of the prefix of that index, i.e. { a: 1 }, assuming none of the index has a sparse or unique constraints, then you can drop the { a: 1 } index.
>
> *MongoDB will be able to use the compound index in all of situations that it would have used the { a: 1 } index.*

In other words, you'll most likely get as good or better performance using a single index, since MongoDB does not have to cache two indexes in memory or update two separate indexes on every insert.